# Error while rendering a form in different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to render a form `app/views/requestforpms/_form.html.erb` in `app/views/passengerrides/show.html.erb`, but getting an error `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` at `<%= form_for @requestforpm do |form| %>`.

app/views/passengerrides/show.html.erb:

```
<%= render partial: 'requestforpms/form' %>
```

app/views/requestforpms/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @requestforpm do |form| %>
   <%= form.hidden_field :passengerride_id, :value => @passengerride.id %>
   <%= form.hidden_field :customer_id, :value => @current_user.id %>
   <%= form.hidden_field :status, :value => 'Request' %>
   <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

apps/controller/requestforpms_controller.rb:

```
class RequestforpmsController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_requestforpms, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def create
  @passengerride =  Passengerride.find (params[:passengerride_id])
  @requestforpm = @passengerride.requestforpms.new(requestforpm_params)

  respond_to do |format|
   if @requestforpm.save
    format.html { redirect_to @passengerride, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @requestforpm, status: :created, location: @requestforpm }
   else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @requestforpm.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
 end

 private
  def set_requestforpms
   @requestforpm = Requestforpm.find(params[:id])
  end


  def requestforpms_params
   params.require(:requestforpm).permit(:passengerride_id, :customer_id, :status)
  end
end
```

**Edit:**

apps/controller/passengerrides_controller.rb:

```
class PassengerridesController < ApplicationController

 before_action :para_passengerride, only: [:edit, :update, :show]
 load_and_authorize_resource :except => :create

 def index
  @q = Passengerride.ransack(params[:q])
  @passengerrides = @q.result(distict: true)
 end

 def new
  @passengerride = Passengerride.new
 end

 def show
 end

 def edit
 end

def create

 @passengerride = Passengerride.new(passengerride_params)
 @passengerride.user = current_user
 if @passengerride.save
  flash[:success] = 'Ride was successfully created.'
  redirect_to passengerride_path(@passengerride)
 else
  render 'new'
 end
end

def update

 @passengerride.user = current_user
 if @passengerride.update(passengerride_params)
  flash[:success] = 'Ride was successfully updated'
  redirect_to passengerride_path(@passengerride)
 else
  render 'edit'
 end
end


def destroy
 @passengerride = Passengerride.find(params[:id])
 @passengerride.destroy
 flash[:danger] = "Ride has been deleted successfully"
 redirect_to passengerrides_path
end

private

 def para_passengerride
  @passengerride = Passengerride.find(params[:id])
 end

private

 def passengerride_params
  params[:passengerride][:sharegasmoney] = params[:passengerride][:sharegasmoney].join(', ')
  params[:passengerride][:okwithgender] = params[:passengerride][:okwithgender].join(', ')
  params[:passengerride][:okwith] = params[:passengerride][:okwith].join(', ')
  params.require(:passengerride).permit(:origin, :destination, :departuretime, :departuredate, :okwithgender, :okwith, :sharegasmoney, :description)
 end
```

end

Comment: Show please `passengerrides` controller with the `show` action.

Comment: @Зелёный I added the passengerrides_controller.rb in the question, please check. And, I have nothing in the show action.

Comment: that's your problem, you have nothing in the show action. Add `@requestforpm` which should contain a valid `@requestforpm` record for the `form_for` method.

Comment: @Зелёный I added this `@requestforpm = Requestforpm.new(passengerride_id: @passengerride.id)` to the show action. It worked, but when I click the submit button, i'm getting an error in the create action in requestforpms_controller.rb. It says `Couldn't find Passengerride with 'id'=`

Comment: StackOverflow it is not your debugging tool, try to understand what you're doing.

Comment: @Зелёный is right .. you had an issue, which he has resolved. You should attempt to figure out why it's now throwing errors and if you really get stuck consider asking a new question (it is a different problem after all).

Comment: @Зелёный, David- Yeah, my bad! Thanks for the answers, I fixed it. :)

Comment: `Passengerride.find (params[:passengerride_id])` <- should there be that space betwen find and a bracket? Line 6 of apps/controller/requestforpms_controller.rb